# Kotlin: why the compiler needs the `const` modifier?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin there are:

- `val` - readonly property
- `const val` - compile-time constants

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants):

> **Compile-Time Constants**
>
> Properties the value of which is known at compile time can be marked as compile time constants using the `const` modifier. Such properties need to fulfill the following requirements:
>
> - Top-level or member of an object
> - Initialized with a value of type String or a primitive type
> - No custom getter

Given that kotlin compiler does know to identify initialized values (such as there is no need defining the variable type in an initializer):

- Why does the compiler needs the programmer's assistance?
- Can't it identify "properties the value of which is known at compile time" and "add" the `const` modifier by itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `const` modifier seriously changes the contract of a property.

For example, if you have a regular property, you may add a special getter to it without affecting the code which uses it.

On the other hand, you would have to recompile the user code in order to remove `const` and add getters. In other words, you loose the advantage of having a property over a field.

Comment: 10x. I think it worth to specifically state: it is not allowed to define a getter to a `const val` property.

Answer (score 3):

Such keywords are helpful in **two** ways:

- They allow the compiler to make stronger assumptions. This enables A)  all kinds of optimization techniques B) stricter checking. If you declare something to be `const`, the compiler can slap your finger when you try to change it.
- They *express* **intention**. Keep in mind that you do not write code to make the compiler happy - but to communicate to other humans reading this code later on.

Meaning: if you don't put down *const* in your source code today - but you also have no statements *modifying* that field ... does that mean you intend that value to be a constant? Would you mind if somebody else adds code that re-assigns that field in some place? By using `const` you make it clear that you do *not* wish that this ever happens.

Comment: "If you declare something to be const, the compiler can slap your finger when you try to change it." - isn't this the case with `val`, already?

Answer (score 3):

I found [Christophe Beyls's article](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-1-fbb9935d9b62) helpful for understanding the "compile-time optimization" of using `const`.

Public `const vals` are converted to values that are accessed directly. Public `vals` are converted to *private*  bytecode values and a synthetic getter is generated.

You can try it yourself by opening up the Kotlin bytecode viewer in Intellij or Android Studio, creating an `object` for some test values, and looking at the synthetic method generated for `val` versus `const val`.

I'm working with an object that defines about 200 constants, and a much smaller file is generated when they're all marked `const val`.